# Mac Low Energy...Developers license necessary to test?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, core-bluetooth

So, I am writing an app for my mac to operate as a central and connect to my iPhone as a peripheral. My iPhone is ready to receive connections and I'm working on the Mac app. When I wrote the iPhone app I found that the simulator in Xcode would not simulate the low-energy functionality and so I purchased an iOS developers license to deploy the app to my phone and test it, which solved my problem.

Now, with the mac app, I think I may be having the same problem...with one difference.

```
- (BOOL) isLECapableHardware
{
    NSString * state = nil;

    switch ([manager state])
    {
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            state = @"The platform/hardware doesn't support Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);

            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            state = @"The app is not authorized to use Bluetooth Low Energy.";
            NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);

            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            state = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
            NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);
            break;
        case CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            return TRUE;
        case CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
        default:
            state = @"Bluetooth is currently powered off.";
            NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);
            return FALSE;

    }
    NSLog(@"Central manager state: %@", state);

    [_textField setStringValue:state];

    return false;        
}
```

When this is called, it always falls all the way through to the default case. With the iPhone app I was falling into state unsupported while trying to test it with the simulator. Does this just mean that I need to buy a mac developers license in addition to the iOS one? Or could there be some other issue?

Comment: You don't need a Mac developer membership to run code on your own machine. What Mac do you have? How are you initialising th central manager?  Where do you invoke the code shown?

Comment: What model Mac do you have? If it's old enough (generally pre-2012) the hardware may not support Bluetooth Low Energy.

Comment: That last log is the only thing logged. It wasn't logging anything at first, then I stuck that log statement in there and it started printing that. That's how I know it's falling all the way through. The iPhone simulator doesn't require a MAC membership either, but you can't get access to the Bluetooth capability with it. I can test the app just fine, just Bluetooth that isn't working. It definitely has low energy capability. It's brand new and other apps can use it. I'm just calling this right after I instantiate the central manager.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?